# Remove all <link> elements inside iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, adal, adal.js

I have some link tags in my `index.html` file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-strap/styles/libs.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-strap/styles/docs.min.css"/>
```

I also use [Adal-JS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) for authentication in AAD.

Adal-JS creates 3 iframes in my page, each is a copy of my `index.html`, therefore each of the `css` files above are downloaded **3 more times** (3 unnecessary times).

I can put a script code to determine if the current `window` is an iframe or the original window.

```
window.IS_ADAL_IFRAME = window.parent !== window;
```

I would like, using that, to clean the `index.html` from any tag that downloads a `script` or a `css`.

My problem is that if the script executes after the `link` tags,then the `css` files were already downloaded. And if the script tag executes before them, then I cannot delete the elements as they do not exist yet.

My goal is to control the files that the iframe fetches, I want to eliminate most of them and keep only the real needed ones.
How can I make this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the linked css files are downloaded several times. They must be cached, and are already in memory after the first time anyway. You can assess this with your browser's dev tools "Performance" and "Network" tabs or similar.

Anyhow one idea could be to utilize the `DOMContentLoaded` (as opposed [to the `load` event](http://javascript.info/tutorial/onload-ondomcontentloaded))

Comment: Even if they are cached, I'd like to spare these downloads if possible.